# Why the width of UIView changed at runtime?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In storyboard the view's width is 346 as the pic shows below

[image]

However, if I run it the width changed to 315 on iPhone 7

[image]

I need the width to create a UITableView as a drag down menu(`_tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 112, myuiview.frame.size.width, 130)];`in viewDidLoad). Since the two widths are different, the UITableView I created does not align to that UIView.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Have you added any autolayout constraints to this view? or any auto resizing mask?

Comment: Are you initialising your myuiview before initialising your table view? You may also consider adding autolayout constraints to both your views.

Comment: I realise because of the autolayout constraints, I need to initialise my UITableView in viewDidAppear. Then it's ok.